# wget entire contents of folder from NGINX server to another server

Tags: nginx, wget

I have a folder on an NGINX server / Debian: `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/scripts/`

I have put in the NGINX Conf for the website:

```
server {
        listen 80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied listen [::]:$
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/default/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name **IP of server**;
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME
                $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;

         }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }

        location /scripts {
                autoindex on;
                allow xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
        }


}
```

Then on a different server, I would like to download the entire contents of the folder scripts using wget or similar.

`wget http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/scripts/` I also tried:

`wget -r --level=0 -E --ignore-length -x -k -p -erobots=off -np -N  http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/scripts/`

`wget -m -nH --cut-dirs=1 -np -R 'index.*'  http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/scripts/`

I have been trying all day however, not joy.

Comment: Try without `--cut-dirs=1`. `wget -m -nH -np -R 'index.*'  http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/scripts/`

Comment: Hello, seems to only get the index.html file and only that.

`Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘scripts/index.html’

scripts/index.html        [ <=>                     ]       0  --.-KB/s   in 0s

Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.
2017-12-27 16:11:35 (0.00 B/s) - ‘scripts/index.html’ saved [0]

Removing scripts/index.html since it should be rejected.
`